# ngdoc: How to document exceptions and events of the method?

Tags: events, exception, angularjs, methods, documentation

I'm currently writing docs for an AngularJS module. Is there a proper way in the ngdoc to document an exceptions and an events which are thrown by a module's method?

**UPD:**
In the [AngularJS contributing guidelines](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute) in the "Applying Code Standards" section is said that *ngdoc* is just an extended version of the *jsdoc* format. Does it mean that I could use @fires and @throws syntax to do what I need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation.
There it is described that an event is declared as

> @ngdoc event

You can put different informations to explain in detail what the event does or when it gets fired or something.

And ngdoc is a customized version of jsdoc, so you could use jsdoc-Tags as well but there are not angular specific!